# Xcode не могу запустить игру на симуляторе

Tags: ios, xcode

Сейчас не могу тестировать на устройстве.

Хотел запустить на симуляторе айфона.

Но в списке не показывает симуляторы, хотя в списке симуляторов они есть и я перед этим установил симулятор  iOS 12.1

В чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: В списке чего ее показывает симуляторы? Что значит "в списке симуляторов они есть", вы же пишете, что их не показывает? Иногда симуляторы пропадают после установки Xcode 10.3, попробуйте перезагрузить компьютер

Answer (score 0):

Моя ошибка оказалась банальной. Собирая игру в Юнити я указал что хочу использовать сдк устройства, а не симулятора.